# Multiple imputation when have more than 1 outcome variable

Tags: multivariate-analysis, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, multivariate-regression

Is there a good paper or reference for doing multiple imputation when there is more than one outcome variable? Anything that specifically addresses building the imputation model or software to use for this imputation would be really great.

Comment: Why should there be any difference?